# Preselecting option in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Trying to implement a popup that allows you to modify an existing database record. As part of this, I have a couple of select boxes that I need to prepopulate with existing selections. This seems harder to do that I first thought. Here's a snippet of what I have as my template

```
{{#with myExistingRecord}}
    <select class="myselect">
        {{#each hoursInTheDay}}
            {{#if isSelectedHour}}
                <option selected>{{this}}</option>
            {{else}}
                <option>{{this}}</option>
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    </select>
{{/with}}
```

The problem I run into is in the `isSelectedHour` template function, because `this` can't have two definitions (the first being the #each value and the second being the record object). I need to compare the value in the #each loop with the value in my record, and I can't think of an elegant way to do this. I could always set my record value as a Session variable, but that's hacky.

Is there a good, non-hacky way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and to my surprise there is a good way to this. You do have access to the outer context in the templating section, and you can use that to pass this to a value to a helper function. I would rewrite your code as follows:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
{{#with myExistingRecord}}
    <select class="myselect">
        {{#each hoursInTheDay}}
            <option {{selected ../recordHour}}>{{this}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
{{/with}}
</template>
```

And then have a helper function:

```
Template.myTemplate.selected = function(hour) {
    if (hour == currentHour)
        { return "selected ";}
    else 
        { return "";}
};
```

Look [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Handlebars) for details on how the ../ notation works.

Comment: The link is dead, and I am curious about the ../ notation. Would you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to create a simple Handlebars helper to handle this. If anyone wants to do something similar, here's the helper code:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('hourOptions', function(selectedHour) {
    var html = '';

    for (var hr = 0; hr < 24; hr++) {
        if (hr === selectedHour)
            html += '<option selected>' + hr + '</option>';
        else
            html += '<option>' + hr + '</option>';
    }

    return new Handlebars.SafeString(html);
});
```

And the template code becomes

```
{{#with myExistingRecord}}
    <select class="myselect">
        {{hourOptions mySelectedHour}}
    </select>
{{/with}}
```